# How do I allocate the memory in this function without any segmentation fault

Tags: c, overflow

When I try to run my programme with this function, I get a segmentation fault, because stack buffer gets overflown. Can somebody help?

```
void converttobin(int a,  int b, char x) {
    char binary[81];
    int number = 0;
    char bit;
    char original[81];
    int dividing = 0;
    number = a;
    size_t len = strlen(binary);
    while (a != 0) {
        dividing = a % 2;
        bit = dividing + '0';
        binary[len++] = bit;
        binary[len] = '\0';
        a = a / 2;
    }
    if (number == 0) {
        a = 0;
        bit = 0 + '0';
        binary[len++] = bit;
        binary[len] = '\0';
    }
    strncpy(original, binary, strlen(original));
    reverse(binary, number, b);
    comparing(binary, original,number, b, x);
    memset(binary, 0, strlen(binary));
    memset(original, 0, strlen(original));
}
```

Comment: `binary` is uninitialized when you call `strlen` on it.

Comment: Have you noticed the fixed formatting of your code that was done by one of the contributors? Please respect it and don't break it with your edits. You have also introduced an unbalanced bracket.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Christian Gibbons points out in his comment, `binary` is un-initialised when you call `strlen` on it.  But what does this mean?

`strlen` walks the array, starting at the first element, counting non-terminating characters.  It doesn't stop until it finds a termination (`'\0'`).  If you're unlucky, that can be a long way into the un-initialised data, and likely to be well past the 81 chars you've allocated.  After a while, strlen starts looking at memory it's not allowed to and you get a segmentation fault (your program has explored outside its allocated segment of memory).

You can resolve this in a few ways.  The simplest is:

```c
char binary[81] = { 0 };
```

This asks the compiler to set the first element to zero (the terminating character).  That's good, because it's the first character strlen will see and stop immediately, reporting your string has length 0.

But looking at your algorithm, you could just ditch the call to strlen altogether and do:

```c
size_t len = 0;
```

But even if you take this approach, it's good practice to initialise your buffers with safe values anyway.

Comment: Tried your suggestion  and it helped me. Thank you very much.